# Bookmarklet to open a webpage and login

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a bookmarklet to open a web page, populate credentials, and click login in one shot. Here is the needed bookmarklets:

For opening a webpage:

```
javascript:location.href='http://www.unt.edu'
```

For Credentials & login:

```
javascript:(function(){var d=document;s=d.querySelector;s.call(d,'input[name*=email]').value='YOUREMAIL@company.com'; s.call(d,'input[name*=pass]').value='SECRETPASSWORDHERE';s.call(d,'button[id*=login],input[type=button][id*=login],.btn-login').click(); }())
```

Is it possible to combine both of them considering the asynchronous behavior of opening the web page?

Comment: It can not be one action in a bookmarklet. The page navigation will prevent it

Comment: I would recommend *not* storing sensitive credential information in this manner, especially without *really* understanding the implications of such a choice. You mentioned in a comment below that you're trying to do this on a machine owned by your work - storing passwords in plain text is likely a violation of your company's information security policy, and doing so also opens you *way* more easily to having this credential information stolen and used maliciously.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I use bookmarklet for testing purposes. there are different type of accounts with the same password. Having them as a bookmarklet library improves my performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine this in one bookmarklet, but you'll have to click it twice. The first click will open a website, and the next one will do the login.

```js
javascript: (() => {
  const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/login';

  if (location.href !== url) return (location.href = url);

  document.querySelector('input#email').value = 'EMAIL';
  document.querySelector('input#password').value = 'PASSWORD';
  document.querySelector('button#submit-button').click();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [a userscript](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) instead, which will run automatically on pageload. Set the userscript's `@includes` to run on `http://www.unt.edu`, then set the userscript's JS to the content of your current bookmarklet:

```
var d=document;s=d.querySelector;s.call(d,'input[name*=email]').value='YOUREMAIL@company.com'; s.call(d,'input[name*=pass]').value='SECRETPASSWORDHERE';s.call(d,'button[id*=login],input[type=button][id*=login],.btn-login').click(); }()
```

(though I'd recommend separating it out onto separate lines for readability and maintainability)

And then use a *plain* bookmark (not a bookmarklet) to `http://www.unt.edu`. This way, whenever you click on the bookmark, the page will load, and when the page loads, the userscript that logs you in will automatically run.

Comment: The above bookmarklets are just a sample that I copied from the Internet. I am not able to install any extension on my browser (my employer's policy) so the only option is pure bookmarklet.